# Difference between "delete" and "call terminate" for WMIC

Tags: windows, wmic

To kill a running process on Windows using its executable path, I could use either of:

```
wmic process where ExecutablePath='C:\\path\\to\\my.exe' delete
```

Or:

```
wmic process where ExecutablePath='C:\\path\\to\\my.exe' call terminate
```

What, if any, is the practical difference between these two approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `call terminate`, we can pass an exit status, such as `call terminate '-1073741510'`. The 32-bit status value has to be signed, and a negative value needs to be quoted. The latter value is `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT` (0xC000013A) as a signed, decimal value. The default exit status is 0, which is the same value that's used for the `delete` verb.

In terms of implementation, the WMI service starts an instance of the WMI Provider Host (wmiprvse.exe) to process the request. It's relatively easy to attach a debugger to inspect this since the provider host process is reused for a few minutes. The [`Win32_Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-process) class is implemented in the WMI Win32 Provider module (cimwin32.dll), which contains a `Process` class with `DeleteInstance` and `ExecTerminate` methods, called respectively for `delete` and `call terminate`. Both methods ultimately call WINAPI `TerminateProcess`.