# End a process started with START command in a Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have the following batch file, which uses ADB to monitor device logs and searches for a string:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Starting log monitor...
START /B adb.exe logcat > log

:LOOP
(TYPE log | FIND "string to find") > NUL
IF "%errorlevel%" == "1" GOTO LOOP

:END
ECHO String found!
```

The script starts the `logcat` command, which runs asynchronously and in the background, using `START /B`.

After the string is found, I would like to end the asynchronous `logcat` command, as it is no longer needed.

Is there any way of the main script telling the asynchronous script to end?

---

I know that I could technically use `adb.exe kill-server` or `taskkill /F /IM adb.exe` to end all ADB processes, but I need to only end the `logcat` command and continue running all other instances of ADB.

Comment: Use `start` with a title and then `taskkill` with a `Windowtitle` filter

Comment: @DavidPostill How do I get that to work? Running `START "log_process" /B adb.exe logcat` and then `TASKKILL /FI "Windowtitle eq log_process"` returns `INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.`.

Comment: The `windowtitle` method works for me. `adb` may substitute your title by its own, so you need to use that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

echo/ starting log monitor...
start /b adb.exe logcat >.\mylogcat.log

:loop
find "string to find" .\mylogcat.log >nul || (
   >nul timeout 15 /nobreak & goto loop ) 
 
echo/ string found!
wmic process where "name like '%%adb.exe%%' and commandline like '%%logcat%%'" delete
```

You can kill your process using the combination of the process name and part of the command line used to start it with `wmic`:

```
wmic process where "name like '%%adb.exe%%' and commandline like '%%logcat%%'" delete
```

You can use the operator **`||`** to keep your loop, and also add a timeout to that monitoring loop...

```
:loop
find "string to find" .\mylogcat.log >nul || (
   >nul timeout 15 /nobreak & goto loop )
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[Timeout](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html)**

  [√] **[Goto :Label](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.htm)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  [√] **[Difference between “delete” and “call terminate” for WMIC](https://superuser.com/a/1410043/969781)**

  [√] **[Understanding start, 2>nul, cmd, and other symbols in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19598997/understanding-start-2nul-cmd-and-other-symbols-in-a-batch-file#:%7E:text=A%20command%20can%20output%20to,So%20nothing%20will%20be%20outputted.&text=Line%204%3A%20hard%20to%20tell%20without%20seeing%20rest%20of%20script.)**

---

---

In PowerShell using *`Get-WmiObject`*:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | % { if ($_.ProcessName -like '*adb.exe*' -and $_.CommandLine -like '*mylogcat.log*') {kill $_.ProcessId}}
```

Using *`Get-CimInstance Win32_Process`*:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='adb.exe'" | % { if ($_.CommandLine -like '*mylogcat.log*') {kill $_.ProcessId}}

# Or.... 
Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name='adb.exe'" | 
% { if ($_.CommandLine -like '*mylogcat.log*') {kill $_.ProcessId}}
```

---

**Additional resources:**

- ***[`wmic /? | www.ss64.com`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yid3Q.png)***
- ***[`Win32_Process` | Some usage examples](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/get-process-owner-and-other-info-with-wmi-and-powershell/)***
- ***[Get Process Owner and Other Info with WMI and PowerShell](https://powershell.one/wmi/root/cimv2/win32_process)***